# Check it in error sp.ribbon.js

Tags: 2013, javascript, error, check-in

Recently I've started getting this error when trying to 'Check it in' while looking at a page. The error in the JavaScript console is:

SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action
File: sp.ribbon.js, Line: 2, Column: 198355

[image]

Update:
The problem seems to be from including sp.js in my master page. When I take that out 'Check it in' works like normal.

Answer (score 1):

Including the scripts after the page has loaded fixed it:

```
var scriptbase = "/_layouts/15/";
$.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js", function () {  
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", function(){
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Taxonomy.js", function() {
            init();
        });
    });
});
```

[source](http://www.vrdmn.com/2012/12/working-with-taxonomy-and-javascript-in.html)